# Single word for a plant's fruit/vegetable?

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm looking for a word that describes the green bulb of a pepper, banana or other mass a plant produces.
A word that encompasses the domains of fruits and vegetables, perhaps a Latin word that's root derives from the Godess of Foliage.
Ideally the word should be scientific and unambigious.

I thought of "appendages" but I interpret that as too alien to a plant, also too ambigious.
I wouldn't call them "extremities", nor would I use "tumor" or "growth" to describe them. The latter are too gross to be associated with edible items.
I feel there must be a better, more scientific, plant related term.

I cannot articulate my question enough for Google to interpret, therefore I come to SE.

**Sample sentence:** "I'm growing peppers and other edible _________" (Note: talking in the domain of plants)

Comment: The community can't be much help with word requests until we have some facts to go on. Please see the [info on word requests](https://english.stackexchange.com/tags/single-word-requests/info). Here's a summary: Describe exactly in what context you want to use the word or phrase--generally we want a sample sentence. Specify the criteria you'll use for accepting answers. Detail the research you've already done. List words or phrases you've already considered but rejected, and explain why. Provide information about the connotation, register, and part of speech you are looking for.

Comment: The parts of a plant which follow the flowers and contain the seeds are its **fruit,** (or perhaps "fruiting body", but that's too technical for your sentence). You used *fruit* in your question title. Why does that not fit?

Comment: @AndrewLeach It needs to include fruit, vegetable, berries; anything a plant makes with, fleshy mass, (containing) seeds. Is there not a word that groups the previous succinctly?

Comment: @WillV Yes, there is. Fruit.

Comment: That would be fruit! Although Peppers and other edible fruits sounds strange because of the ambiguity between "fruit" and plants which bare fruit. **"I'm growing peppers and other pants which bare edible fruit"** might be closer to what you want from a clarity standpoint?

Comment: @AndrewLeach I actually Googled the definition of "Fruit". Sure enough, you are correct. For such a detailed definition the word "Fruit" seems too simple. Would people study "Fruitology"?

Comment: What @AndrewLeach said. It includes the fruit part of what are commonly thought of as (some) vegetables (as food), such as tomatoes, eggplant, squash, and peppers. It does not include stem, root, or leaf parts that we also eat as "vegetables".

Comment: If you're looking for a scientific term, then you need to consider that botanically speaking, [there's no such thing as a vegetable](http://www.bbc.com/earth/story/20150917-do-vegetables-really-exist).

Answer (score 3):

I would use Produce as a generic for fruits and vegetables.

I'm growing peppers and other edible **Produce**

**Produce** (noun)

1. things that have been produced or grown, especially by farming.
   "dairy produce"

synonyms: food, foodstuff(s), products; harvest, crops, fruit, vegetables, greens 
"fresh produce"

However if you specifically mean the part of the plant containing seeds, as your comment implies, then Fruit is the correct word:

**Fruit** (noun)

1. the sweet and fleshy product of a tree or other plant that **contains seed** and can be eaten as food.

Comment: I like this, it works well. Makes me feel like a farmer.

Comment: But milk and cheese are dairy products. 'Products' is too general, and 'fruit' would never be used for cabbage etc.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I agree "products" would be a poor choice, hence my suggestion of "produce" not products.  The awkward term "dairy produce" is strictly from the definition.  As an example, cabbages are often found in a grocer's produce section.

Comment: Apologies. 'Produce' is too general also. Milk and cheese are classed as  dairy produce, which is defined as 'food derived from or containing milk and its derivatives' [[Collins Cobuild](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/dairy-produce)]. And Collins [ibid] has << produce: anything that is produced; product >>.